# How can I obtain the minimum date for a value that is equal to the maximum date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to obtain the minimum start date for a query, in which the value is equal to its maximum date. So far, I'm able to obtain the value in it's maximum date, but I can't seem to obtain the minimum date where that value remains the same.

Here is what I got so far and the query result:

```
select a.id, a.end_date, a.value
from database1 as a
inner join (
    select id, max(end_date) as end_date
    from database1
    group by id
) as b on a.id = b.id and a.end_date = b.end_date
where value is not null
order by id, end_date
```

This result obtains the most recent record, but I'm looking to obtain the most minimum end date record where the value remains the same as the most recent.

In the following sample table, this is the record I'd like to obtain the record from the row where id = 3, as it has the minimum end date in which the value remains the same:

| id | end_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/12/22 | 5 |
| 2 | 02/13/22 | 5 |
| 3 | 02/14/22 | 4 |
| 4 | 02/15/22 | 4 |

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: I use SQL server

Comment: A table named database1 is very confusing,

Comment: So you want where `max(end_date) = min(end_date)` ?

Comment: I want min(end_date) where value is the same from max(end_date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option that just approaches the problem somewhat as described for the sample data as shown - Get the value of the maximum date and then the minimum id row that has that value:

```
select  top(1) t.*
from (
    select top(1) Max(end_date)d, [value] 
    from t 
    group by [value] 
    order by d desc 
)d
join t on t.[value] = d.[value]
order by t.id;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=26062f1e49825268bdb83747931d92a9)

Answer (score 0):

I'm most likely overthinking this as a Gaps & Island problem, but you can do:

```
select min(end_date) as first_date
from (
  select *, sum(inc) over (order by end_date desc) as grp
  from (
    select *,
      case when value <> lag(value) over (order by end_date desc) then 1 else 0 end as inc
    from t
  ) x
) y
where grp = 0
```

Result:

```
first_date
----------
2022-02-14
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c92bb/3).

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by value) as rn,
        last_value(value) over (order by end_date) as lv
    from T
)
select * from data
where value = lv and rn = 1
```

This isn't looking strictly for streaks of consecutive days. Any date that happened to have the same value as on final date would be in contention.